# Copy logs file to another path laravel

Tags: laravel, local-storage

I want to get a copy of the logs file using programmability,   I just tried to copy the files using this command

```
   $co= Storage::copy('logs/laravel-'.$start.'.log',$filename);
           dd($co);
```

but I have an error which says the file does not exist,
I believe that is because storage looking in  the default driver of the config file, how can I tell laravel to look in logs folder when I want to run the copy command, is there any way to do that .

Comment: you can change the driver on the fly `Storage::disk('default')->copy($from, $to);`

Comment: thank you for reply , but  this way copy file from storage folder to another folder inside storage  folder , I want to copy logs file from storage to the root directory or desktop in ubuntu

Comment: first get the file `$file = Storage::disk('default')->get($from);` then store it `Storage::disk('yourDisk')->put($path, $file);`

Comment: actually I want dynamic  copy file , the user will determine the path that he want to save the logs file and then copy the files from storage to the path that determined by user

Comment: So the `$path` variable in the copy is the user's chosen path

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
 You can get the path of the log file with `storage_path()` and copy your file anywhere you want with php `copy` function 
I think that is a easy way that you can do it:

```php
<?php  
function copyLogFile($logFileName, $destination)
{
    $logPathDir = storage_path().'/logs/';
    $logFilePath = $logPathDir . $logFileName; 

    if (file_exists($logFilePath)) {
        if( !@copy($logFilePath, $destination) ) {  
            echo "File can't be copied! \n";  
            $errors= error_get_last();
            echo "COPY ERROR TYPE: ".$errors['type'].PHP_EOL;
            echo "COPY ERROR MESSAGE: ".$errors['message'];
        }  
        else {  
            echo "File has been copied! \n";  
        }  
    } else {
        echo "The file $logFilePath does not exist";
    }

}

// Store the path of destination file 
$destination = '/home/azibom/Desktop/backup.log';  

// Your log file name
$start = "2020-01-01";
$logFileName = 'laravel-'.$start.'.log';

copyLogFile($logFileName, $destination);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , actually it must work , but unfortunately it is not , I don't know why , can not copy the file even I set 7777 to the source and destination folder

Comment: I update my answer please check it out, and if you get an error please write it for me

Comment: I change my answer again, can you please check it out and again write the error for me

Comment: that what I have File can't be copied! COPY ERROR TYPE: COPY ERROR MESSAGE:

Comment: Do you use absolute path in your `$destination` var?

Comment: yes I am using the /var/www/html/Backup as path of destination

Comment: are you using docker?

Comment: can you make a directory and name it `test` in /var/www/html/, and then put `/var/www/html/test/my.log` in your `$destination` var and test it